# Currying makes the base function not work?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Am I doing this incorrectly, or is this a problem with currying in general?

Take this example in Javascript.

```js
let addNormal = (x,y) => x+y;
let addCurry = x => y => x+y;

let increment = addCurry(1);

/// Below returns 4.
alert(increment(3));

/// Below returns 4.
alert(addNormal(1,3));

/// Below returns y => x+y
alert(addCurry(1,3));
```

I mean functional programming seems great, but this seems like an anti-pattern if the base function doesn't work as intended. The example from above was taken from a hackernoon blog. [Partial Application of Functions](https://hackernoon.com/partial-application-of-functions-dbe7d9b80760)

Comment: There is a problem with your terminology. Use initial function of the sequence rather than base function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called the `addCurry` wrong.

Call `addCurry(1)(3)` instead of `addCurry(1,3)`. Why? Because

```
addCurry = x => y => x + y;
```

is the same as

```
function addCurry(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

```js
let addNormal = (x,y) => x+y;
let addCurry = x => y => x+y;

let increment = addCurry(1);

/// Below returns 4.
alert(increment(3));

/// Below returns 4.
alert(addNormal(1,3));

/// Below returns y => x+y
alert(addCurry(1)(3));
```